# Numerical solution of IVP for linear ODE with variable coefficient runs wild soon

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Cross posted [in scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19478/5331).

A friend of mine showed me this initial value problem (IVP) for a linear ordinary differential equation (ODE) with variable coefficient:

$$y''(x)=\left(x^2-1\right) y(x)$$$$y(0)=1$$$$y'(0)=0$$

Seems to be a simple one, right? Actually it can be solved analytically by `DSolve`:

```
asol = DSolve[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> E^(-(x^2/2))}}
> ```

But its numerical solution given by `NDSolve` runs wild very fast:

```
l = 10;
nsol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, l}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Manipulate[Plot[y[x] /. nsol // Evaluate, {x, 0, l2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-10, 1}}], {l2, 1/10, 7}]
```

> ```
> {0.015600, Null}
> ```

[image]

How to resolve the problem?

Well, actually I found two solution for this problem but one is time-consuming and the other is limited so **I'm not quite satisfied**.

**Solution 1**

A higher `WorkingPrecision` will help:

```
l = 10;
nsol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
    y, {x, 0, l}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]; // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[y[x] /. nsol, {x, 0, l}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
> {2.857000, Null}
> ```

[image]

Nonetheless, this solution is **slow**, and will need a higher `WorkingPrecision` and be even slower when `l` gets larger.

**Solution 2**

Noticing the analytic solution involves a `Exp`, given the experience that `Exp` often causes trouble in numerical calculation, the transformation $y(x)=e^{z(x)}$ is used:

```
l = 50;
rule = y -> (Exp[z@#] &);

(* z[0] == 0 is manually substituted because it seems that 
   NDSolveValue has some difficulty in understanding y[0] == 1 /. rule *)
nsol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], z[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0} /. rule, 
  z, {x, 0, l}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[Exp@nsol[x], {x, 0, l}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
>  {0.013000, Null}
> ```

[image]

However, as mentioned above, this solution is **limited**, I wouldn't have thought it out if I was unaware of the analytic solution, and I really doubt if this method can be extended: I guess there's a sort of problem behind this specific example, once it's solved, more complicated problem might be solved too, for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72921/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80692/1871).

I'd appreciate if anyone can give an in-depth explanation for the problem or find a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this shows what the problem is.  The ODE is inherently numerically unstable as any deviation from the exact solution goes to ±∞.

```
asol = DSolve[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == p}, y[x], x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[y[x] /. asol /. {{p -> 0}, {p -> 10^(-error)}, {p -> -10^(-error)}} // Evaluate,
  {x, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> 2],
 {error, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update - Possible workaround**

Aside from increasing the working precision and increasing the `"DifferenceOrder"`, one can try the approach I took toward the Airy equation in my answer to [how to solve ODE with boundary at infinity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/how-to-solve-ode-with-boundary-at-infinity/59277#59277), which is similar both in form and in having a single solution (for a given initial value for `y[0]`) that does not diverge to infinity.  For that approach, we have to set up the problem as a boundary-value problem on $[0, \infty)$ instead of an initial-value problem.  One can see from the equation that $y = 0$ is a solution, and that for some $x > 1$, if $y$, $y'$ are both positive or both negative, the solution diverges.  Thus if a solution crosses the $x$-axis, it will diverge.  And if $y$ is positive (negative) and reaches a local minimum (maximum resp.), then $y$ will diverge.  Further $y$ cannot approach a finite nonzero value because $|y''|$ will be bounded away from $0$.  One might surmise that there is a solution that starts at $y = 1$ and approaches $y = 0$.  (It's harder to know that this will have the initial condition $y' = 0$, but I suppose one could check that afterwards.  If it doesn't satisfy it, then I suppose the IVP actually has a diverging solution and the straightforward `NDSolve` solution should be used.)

First we transform the differential equation with the substitutions $x = \tan t$ and $u(t) = y(\tan t)$ to transform $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\pi/2]$.  (You might want to evaluate the `NestList` separately if you cannot see what it does.)

```
eqn = (-(x[t]^2 - 1) y[x[t]]
  + D[D[y[x[t]], t]/D[x[t], t], t]/D[x[t], t]) x'[t]^3 == 0 /. 
   x -> Tan;
bvp = {eqn, u[0] == 1, u[Pi/2] == 0} /. 
   Solve[NestList[D[#, t] &, u[t] == y[Tan[t]], 2],
    {y''[Tan[t]], y'[Tan[t]], y[Tan[t]]}];

femsol = y -> (u[ArcTan[#]] &) /. 
  First@NDSolve[bvp, u, {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}]

Plot[y[x] /. femsol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comparison with the exact solution:

```
Plot[Exp[-x^2/2] - (y[x] /. femsol) // Evaluate, {x, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The `"DifferenceOrder"` seems not to be helpful here, at least when it's together with `"ImplicitRungeKutta"` or `"ExplicitRungeKutta"`…

Comment: @xzczd I found it modestly helpful, in that increasing it made the divergence occur a little bit later (but not much later).  `"DifferenceOrder" -> 9` with `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` diverged around `x == 8`, as I recall.  Since it was so modest, I didn't include an example.

Comment: You may want to take part in [the discussion here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) :D, currently the transformation can be done by `Assuming[0 < t < Pi/2, dChange[{y''[x] == (x^2 - 1) y[x], y[0] == 1, y[Infinity] == 0}, ArcTan@x == t, x, t, y[x]]]`.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks.  I'm sure what to add to the discussion, but thanks for linking to that useful answer!