# Solving parametric ODEs at large parameter values

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, parametric-functions

Question [101668](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101668/solving-ode-in-mathematica#comment276089_101668) was not particularly clear and was put on hold for that reason.  The author did clarify it a bit, but it seems unlikely that the question will be reopened.  Through an exchange of comments with the author, I believe that I understand what he asking, which I present here and for which I offer an answer.  Perhaps others can offer better answers.

The OP wishes to solve the system of equations

```
{f'''[x] + f[x] f''[x] + 4 - f'[x] f'[x] == 0, g''[x] + p[[i]] f[x] g'[x] == 0,
    f[0] == f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == -1, f'[5] == 2, g[5] == 0}
```

for a set of parameter values.

```
p = {0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.72, 1, 5, 7, 10, 100, 1000};
```

The obvious approach is

```
a = ParametricNDSolve[{f'''[x] + f[x] f''[x] + 4 - f'[x] f'[x] == 0, 
    g''[x] + p0 f[x] g'[x] == 0, f[0] == f'[0] == 0, g'[0] == -1, 
    f'[5] == 2, g[5] == 0}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 5}, {p0}];
```

over the domain `{x, 0, 5}`, which works well for `p` as large as `7`

```
Plot[Evaluate[{g[7][x] /. a, f[7][x] /. a}], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

but appears to become unstable for larger values of `p`.  (According to the OP, Maple can solve this problem for large `p` without difficulty.)  One might hope that adding the options

```
Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> Infinity
```

would provide large `p` answers, but it is exceedingly slow.  Setting

```
WorkingPrecision-> 30
```

instead helps a bit, but not much.  It too is slow.  The question, then, is - how to obtain solutions for large `p` in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach to obtaining large `p` results involves two observations.  First, `f` is independent of `p` and can be solved at the outset.

```
sf = First[f /. NDSolve[{f'''[x] + f[x] f''[x] + 4 - f'[x] f'[x] == 0, 
    f[0] == f'[0] == 0, f'[5] == 2}, f, {x, 0, 5}]];
```

Second, a first integral exists for the ODE involving `g`.

```
lgp = -Integrate[sf[x], x];
```

where `lgp` is `Log[g'[x]]` for `p = 1`.  Thus, two applications of `Integrate` produce a solution.

```
hp[p0_?NumericQ] := FunctionInterpolation[-Exp[p0 lgp], {x, 0, 5}, 
    InterpolationPoints -> 1000, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
h[p0_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := -Integrate[hp[p0][x0], {x0, x, 5}]
```

Note that `InterpolationPoints` must be fairly large to provide reasonable accuracy at large `p`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[h[1000, x]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, g[1000]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80828/1871). Based on the experience got in that post, first analyse the equation a bit:

```
DSolve[{g''[x] + p0 f[x] g'[x] == 0(*, g[0] == 0*), g'[0] == 0}, g[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{g[x] -> C[2]}}
> ```

Apparently the solution will be `{{g[x] -> 0}}` if `g[0] == 0` (though `DSolve` will fail if this b.c. is directly included in it), which suggests that we can force `g[x]` and `g'[x]` to be exact `0` once they're close enough to `0` to avoid the error accumulation. So here comes the solution:

```
sf = NDSolveValue[{f'''[x] + f[x] f''[x] + 4 - f'[x] f'[x] == 0, f[0] == f'[0] == 0, 
    f'[5] == 2}, f, {x, 0, 5}];

sg = With[{p0 = 1000, f = sf, e = $MachineEpsilon}, 
  NDSolveValue[{g''[x] + p0 f[x] g'[x] == 0, g'[0] == -1, g[5] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[{g[x] < e, g'[x] < e}, {g[x] -> 0, g'[x] -> 0}]}, g, {x, 0, 5}]]

Plot[sg[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]