# Unexpected/unphysical behavior of ODE near singularity

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I'm trying to solve an ODE that becomes stiff or singular at a point. The ODE and initial conditions are

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2 z}{dt^2} &= f(z) f'(z) \bigg(1-\frac{3 \eta^2}{2} f(z) \bigg)\\
\frac{dz}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=t_0} &= \sqrt{1-\eta^2}\\
z\big|_{t=t_0}&=0.
\end{align*}$$

where $f(z) = 1+\frac{z^2}{l^2} - \frac{\mu^d z^d}{l^{2d}}$. Here, $\mu$, $d$, and $l$ are constants, $\eta$ is an adjustable parameter between $0$ and $1$, and $t_0$ denotes the initial time.

I've implemented the system in the code snippet below:

```
d = 3;
l = 5.; μ = 26.^(1/d);

f[z_] := 1 + z^2/l^2 - μ^d z^d/l^(2 d);

Subscript[θ, 0] = 2.4;
tSoln = ParametricNDSolve[{ZZ''[t] == f[ZZ[t]] f'[ZZ[t]] (1 - (3 η^2)/2 f[ZZ[t]]), 
    ZZ'[-l Subscript[θ, 0]] == Sqrt[1 - η^2], 
    ZZ[-l Subscript[θ, 0]] == 0}, {ZZ}, 
    {t, -l Subscript[θ, 0], l Subscript[θ, 0]}, {η}]
z[t_, η_] := ZZ[η][t] /. tSoln;

Plot[z[t, 0], {t, -5*2.4, 5*2.4}]
```

From the underlying physics, I know that for sufficiently small $\eta$, the function $z(t)$ should asymptotically approach a constant value (here $z \to 25$). However, I believe the system becomes stiff/singular as $z(t)$ approaches that value, and *Mathematica* doesn't find the correct solution.

As an example, the above code gives me this plot of $z(t)$: [image: wrong z(t)]

For some reason, the graph dips downward. (With other small, nonzero values of $\eta$, the graph crosses the asymptote of $z=25$.) If I take the $\eta=0$ case and integrate it directly rather than via an ODE solver, I obtain the behavior that I expect:

[image: more correct z(t)]

Is there an ODE solution method that is particularly suited for this problem? I've mixed and matched with `"BDF"`, `"StiffnessSwitching"`, and some others without really understanding how they work, and none of them give consistent results. How should I approach this?

**In short:** How can I get *Mathematica* to understand the correct asymptotic behavior of a differential equation when it becomes stiff or singular?

Sorry for such a lengthy post, it's kind of hard for me to articulate the exact problem. I'm also not very familiar with the advanced tools of *Mathematica*, so I very much appreciate any guidance. Thank you so much! (Please let me know if I can clarify anything.)

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of precision. `WorkingPrecision -> 32` will resolve your problem:

```
d = 3;
l = 5; μ = 26^(1/d);

f[z_] = 1 + z^2/l^2 - μ^d z^d/l^(2 d);

Subscript[θ, 0] = 24/10;
tSoln = ParametricNDSolve[{ZZ''[t] == f[ZZ[t]] f'[ZZ[t]] (1 - (3 η^2)/2 f[ZZ[t]]), 
    ZZ'[-l Subscript[θ, 0]] == Sqrt[1 - η^2], 
    ZZ[-l Subscript[θ, 0]] == 0}, {ZZ}, {t, -l Subscript[θ, 0], 
    l Subscript[θ, 0]}, {η}, WorkingPrecision -> 32];
z[t_, η_] = ZZ[η][t] /. tSoln;

Plot[z[t, 0], {t, -5*2.4, 5*2.4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cool! That does seem to be the case in this instance. However, I'm a bit hesitant to accept this answer because it doesn't seem to work as well for different values of $d$. For example, if I run the code as shown with $d=3$, the plot outputs immediately and exhibits the correct behavior. However, with $d=4$ or $d=5$, these are no longer true. Would I just need more `WorkingPrecision` for these cases? Is there a more "universal" method that takes known asymptotic behavior into account and works roughly equally for different cases of $d$?

Comment: @qm-arv Choosing `WorkingPrecision -> 48` together with `Method -> ExplicitRungeKutta` (or the calculation will be too slow) seems to handle $d=4$ and $5$. I guess this behavior might be similar to the one mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80828/1871), if so, there doesn't exist a more general solution for so long, as far as I know. Anyway, feel free to wait for a moment, maybe someone more knowledgable will come up with a better answer :) .