# Diverging solution to radial equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, eigenvalues

I want to solve a seemingly simple eigenvalue problem. I have a fixed set of boundary conditions given and want to change the complex parameter omega in to minimize exponentially falling solutions for some large r value. However, for the regime of omega, in which I expect to get exponentially falling solutions, I only obtain exponentially growing solutions. Therefore, I can't even attempt to minimize the result at some finite but large r.

```
rstart = 2 + 0.001;
f[r_] := 1 - 1/r
eq = f[r] D[f[r] D[R[r], r],r] - (w^2 + f[r] ((l (l + 1))/r^2 + m^2))R[r] == 0 /. {l -> 1,m -> 4/10, w -> wr + I wi}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq, R[rstart] == 1, R'[rstart] == 1},R, {r, rstart, 100}, {wr, wr}]
test = Table[Log[Abs[R[wr, wi][r]]] /. sol, {wr, 0.88, 1, 0.01}, {wi, 10^-4,10^-1, 10^-2}];
Plot[test, {r, rstart, 100}]
```

I have also looked at other people's posts, though, there the minimization was done with respect to the initial conditions, which are fixed in my case. I have also tried the same with an increased `MaxStepSize`, but also that was unsuccessful.

Comment: Probably you have an implicit BC of the solution being zero at $ r = \infty $, right? Just force it to be zero at the end of your range.

Comment: But how would I force it to be zero, if I have the given initial conditions and want to determine w, by setting the solution to zero at infinity?

Comment: "However, for the regime of omega, in which I expect to get exponentially falling solutions, I only obtain exponentially growing solutions. " Then are you sure the underlying model itself is correct?

Comment: @xzczd: it's possible that the OP's DE does have a growing and a decaying solution, but the condition of the problem is bad enough that integrating forward yields a linear combination of the growing and decaying solution, which is of course itself growing.

Comment: The ODE has the asymptotic limit `R''[r] - (w^2 + m^2} R[r] == 0`, which will have exponential or oscillatory solutions, depending on the value of `(w^2 + m^2}`.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Do you mean something similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80828/numerical-solution-of-ivp-for-linear-ode-with-variable-coefficient-runs-wild-soo)?

Comment: @xzczd, like that, yes. Similar things happen when trying to numerically integrate the modified Bessel DE, where any inexact computation will have $K$ swamping out any of $I$'s contributions in the long run.

Comment: So the numerical solution is leaking into the exponentially growing branch, which then starts to dominate at some point? But then I should at least obtain a exponentially decaying solution in the beginning (given the initial data and parameters would give an exponentially decaying solution).